# specifying multiple separate random effects in nlme

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I am analysing some whale tourism data and am trying to construct linear mixed effect models in the `nlme` package to see if any of my explanatory variables affect encounter time between whales and tourists. (I am also open to running this model in `lme4`.)

My variables are:

- `mins`: encounter time (response variable)
- `Id`: individual whale ID (random effect)
- `Vessel`: vessel Id (random effect)
- `Sex`: sex of the animal
- `Length`: length of the animal
- `Year`
- `Month` (nested within `Year`).

So my random variables are `Id` and `Vessel` and I also have `Year` and `Month` as nested random effects.

I have come up with the following:

```
form1 <- formula(Min ~ length + Sex+ Encounter)
 model1 <- lme(form1, 
              random = list(Id = ~1, 
                            Vessel = ~1, 
                            Year=~1,
                            Month = ~1), data=wsdata, method="ML")
```

But all my random effects become nested within `Id`.

Is there any way I can define `Id` and `Vessel` as separate random effects and `Year` and `Month` as nested random effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it's much easier to specify *crossed* (what you mean by "separate", I think) random effects in `lme4`, so unless you need models for temporal or spatial autocorrelation or heteroscedasticity (which are still easier to achieve with `nlme`), I would go ahead with

```
library(lme4)
fit <- lmer(mins ~ Length + Sex+ (1|Id) + (1|Vessel) +
                (1|Year/Month), data=wsdata, REML=FALSE)
```

A few other comments:

- what is `encounter`?  it was in your formula but not in your description of the data set
- it seems quite likely that encounter times (a duration of encounters?) would be skewed, in which case you might want to log-transform them.

Comment: Thanks Ben!  Encounter is the number of times each individual was encountered (I just labelled these 1, 2, 3 so on).  You are right the duration of encounter is skewed and I have tried log transforming them, but does this affect the way I have to interpret my models?

Comment: well, it means you will be modeling *proportional* changes in encounter duration with respect to covariates (and the encounter durations will be assumed to be log-Normally distributed among individuals, vessels, etc.).

Comment: Ok, got it. The log-transformed model looks a lot better already. Thanks for the help